# Bootstrap - Getting buttons aligned with unequal amounts of text and using matchHeight.js

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8y1sgo58/

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and the [Match height](http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/jquery.matchheight) plugin. This lets me create equal height boxes:

[image]

But I want the buttons (marked "Link") to appear in the same position horizontally.

How can I do this with unequal amounts of content inside my boxes as shown?

I tried applying Match Height again - where the content resides, e.g.

```
<div class="home-box-text match-height">
```

But this doesn't fix the problem. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each of the `<p>` tags containing the box description, I added a class `.text-container` and then used the match height JQuery plugin on that class which seemed to work.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8y1sgo58/3/).

Comment: It's really strange because that works fine on the fiddle. In my application it didn't work. But if I add `.text-container` to `<div class="home-box-text">` it fixes it. Strange! Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

I will just put a `min-height: 80px;` on your `<p>` tag.
Note sure if it's the best method or a good practice but it works.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7yrz9sf0/)

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried something similar but don't like coding in `min-height`s because it's a responsive application. I know I could use media queries but it's really prone to breaking especially if the users add more or less text (this is part of a content mangeable application)

Comment: Yes you have to do something with the matchHeight jQuery plugin. I will try to give you a better solution.

Comment: I'm already using Match height and wasn't sure if it could be used twice, because when i tried applying it as shown in my post, it breaks! Thanks for your help...

Answer (score -1):

give the buttons position: absolute; may be it will work.

Comment: It just makes the button go outside the box and doesn't help in any way. Feel free to try it...there's a fiddle up there...

Comment: Resize your browser window smaller. See what happens? It's a responsive app, and the buttons will overlap the text on smaller devices.